# How to extract third party application data (mp3 files) from iPhone6 to Windows 10 computer

Tags: iphone, windows, data-transfer, pc, third-party

I need to extract (download) from my iPhone 6 the data from third party application (mp3 files) to my Windows 10 PC. The data load to iPhone were from this third party application (radio.kartina) and were NOT using iTunes or any Apple applications.

Any applications I can download to iPhone and/or PC to have this access?

The USB connection gives me access to photos (and videos) only, but I need to get these mp3 files from iPhone 6 to my Windows 10 PC.

I would appreciate any help - name of application to use or detail instructions. Regards, Simon.

Answer (score 1):

**iFunbox** or **iTools** is the program you need to backup iPhone data to computer. iFunbox provides an easy way to manipulate app data in sanbox. Both of them are free programs and easy to use.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 8.3, Apple blocked access to files in applications that don't have "iTunes File Sharing" enabled. If the app in question supports this, then you can use iTunes to transfer the files off. If it doesn't, the best (and possibly only) solution is to back up your device and use a program on your computer such as iExplorer (or a similar application), and the "Backup Explorer" (again other apps may have a similar function), to browse your backup.

I have not tested this and it may no longer work with the latest versions of iOS or iExplorer (or other similar app).

If you are running a version of iOS below 8.3 you can use iExplorer (or similar) to transfer the files from your device without backing up first.